# Uniq a specific field in wireshark

Tags: ubuntu, dns, wireshark, uniq, tshark

lets assume that I captured the following packets:

- DNS response Answer: 192.168.14.258
- DNS response Answer: 192.168.14.258, 15.36.88.1 (sometimes there's more than one IP returned in a dns respone)
- DNS response Answer: 192.168.14.258
- DNS response Answer: 15.36.88.1

How do I uniq it? I want to have as a result the following:

- 192.168.14.258
- 15.36.88.1

It's all new to me so please explain your answer as much as possible.

thanks the helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick (if you only want the IPv4 addresses):

```
tshark  -r input.pcap -Y dns.a -T fields -e dns.a | grep -Po "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" | sort -u
```

---

**Explanations**

1. `-Y dns.a` to select only packets that have a DNS A record.
2. `-T fields -e dns.a` to display the address field of the DNS A record.
3. The tshark command will output the list of addresses for each packet. `grep -Po "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"` will extract each IP, each on a new line.
4. `| sort -u` to sort and remove duplicates from the output of the `grep` command.